# GQL Query with __key__ in List of KEYs

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

In the [GQL reference](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html), it is encouraged to use the `IN` keyword with a list of values, and to construct a Key from hand the GQL query

```
SELECT * FROM MyModel WHERE __key__ = KEY('MyModel', 'my_model_key')
```

will succeed. However, using the code you would expect to work:

```
SELECT * FROM MyModel WHERE __key__ IN (KEY('MyModel', 'my_model_key1'),
                                        KEY('MyModel', 'my_model_key2'))
```

in the Datastore Viewer, there is a complaint of "Invalid GQL query string."

What is the correct way to format such a query?

UPDATE: This is not possible to do with the current SDK. As I note in my comment, when using a list, only a reference (e.g. `:1` or `:email`) or an int, float, string, boolean or null literal are acceptable list entries.

**SECOND UPDATE: I fixed the bug and it is now possible to perform such queries. Fix can be found in Google Code Hosting  [diff](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/diff?spec=svn241&r=241&format=side&path=/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/gql/__init__.py&old_path=/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/gql/__init__.py).**

PS I know there are more efficient ways to do this in Python (without constructing a GQL query) and using the remote_api, but each call to the remote_api counts against quota. In an environment where quota is not (necessarily) free, quick and dirty queries are very helpful.

Comment: Do you really think that the number of entities you fetch by hand in the console is going to add to a significant amount of consumed quota if you did it via remote_api?

Comment: No. Again, I'm just wondering how to structure the query correctly. The second snippet in my post looks like it would not be an "Invalid GQL query string". Is it the case that `WHERE __key__ IN` is invalid GQL?

Comment: I'm still confused why you want to do this, though. It's a particularly inefficient way to fetch entities.

Comment: It was really a proof of concept, nothing more. I guess we can agree to let the question die due to lack of practicality.

Comment: This would be useful to me when debugging from the Data Viewer in the admin console.

Comment: OK I finally tracked down the issue. When a list is used, the values in the list are parsed using the `__GetValueList` method which only uses the `__Reference` [method](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/gql/__init__.py#1125) and `__Literal` [method](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/gql/__init__.py#1147) from the `GQL` class to parse objects. I'm looking into why `=` works with a KEY (without a reference or literal) and possibly submitting a patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the [fix](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/diff?spec=svn241&r=241&format=side&path=/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/gql/__init__.py&old_path=/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/gql/__init__.py) was implemented, the code snippet from the original post will suffice:

```
SELECT * FROM MyModel WHERE __key__ IN (KEY('MyModel', 'my_model_key1'),
                                        KEY('MyModel', 'my_model_key2'))
```

PS I realized my comment on the original post may not be sufficiently clear as an answer to future viewers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand. Your objective is to view a specific list of entities in the Datastore Viewer to avoid consuming quota? I don't know of a way to do this with GQL, but you can access entities directly if you know their key, e.g.:

https://appengine.google.com/datastore/edit?app_id=myapp&key=key1

https://appengine.google.com/datastore/edit?app_id=myapp&key=key2

If you're doing this in code, please don't try use GQL. Use `db.get(keys)` or something similar.

Comment: I have no issues using `db.get` or `MyModel.get_by_key_name` or `MyModel.get_by_id`. The question was fueled by the desire to know how it could be done. Even doing individual queries (as with `key=` in the query string) can be accomplished with `SELECT * FROM MyModel WHERE __key__ = KEY('MyModel', 'my_model_key')`, as I mentioned.